# Git - Your branch is ahead by 5 commits

Tags: git

In my git repo, There are two branches except `master`. `nyteam` and `cfteam`.

Switch to `nyteam` branch

Commit some changes and pushed to `origin/nyteam`
(so far only one commit is pushed)

Switch to `cfteam`

```
git status
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/cfteam'

git pull origin nyteam
git status

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/cfteam' by 5 commits.
```

Now the question is, where does the other four commits come in place which is actually not done by me.

Can anyone explain this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now the question is, where does the other four commits come in place which is actually not done by me.

in order to view the history do this:

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

It will show you the commits in which the branches are pointing to.

---

#### where does the other four commits come from?

When you executed:

```
git pull origin nyteam
```

`nyteam` added 4 commits into your current branch which is `cfteam` so now you have **new** commits which came from the merged branch.

---

Here is a sample of something similar:

[image]

```
git log after the merge (pull = fetch + merge)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. the `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` gives the below response `a249689 (HEAD -> cfteam, origin/nyteam, nyteam)`

Comment: This means that the 3 branches pointing to the same commit. all of them. checkout the origin/cfteam branch (you will be in detached head) and see to which commit its pointing to. `git checkout origin/cfteam`

Comment: I am in origin/cfteam, I dont see the five commits. Does that mean origin/cfteam is not having these commits but cfteam does ?

Comment: Exactly.  Since you have it locally but you didn't pushed it yet

Comment: Do you have better understanding now?

Comment: Yes. Now it is clear.. Thanks for your time. Accepting it

Comment: Feel free to ask more if nedded.  Glad to help

Comment: Read this out to understand it better. (feel free to vote if you like it). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716

Comment: Upvoted that also..  You are so good at Git especially in explaining

Answer (score 1):

The two branches diverged at a point in the past. The changes to nyteam are represented by four commits. When you do a pull from cfteam into nyteam it has merged the new changed onto the state arrived at by the previous four commits. So the fifth node is a merge, the four before that are the changes in that branch. You are "ahead" because you have cfteam as the origin that nyteam is tracking against.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But when i create this new branch `nyteam`, i was in cfteam. So i guess the `nyteam` should be similar to the cfteam at the beginning. then i did a commit. What is the possibility of the other four commits in this ?